# Calculating number of values in list in attribute using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I just want to count the values in a list (NEIGHBORS) for each object in my layer and put the result in a column (NUMBER).

[image]

My code is not working

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
test = iface.activeLayer()
v1 =  QgsVectorLayer("NUMBER")
with edit (v1):
    for f in v1.getFeatures():
        f ["NUMBER"] = f[len('NEIGHBORS')]
        v1.updateFeature(f)
```

and has the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.15\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.15/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py", line 38, in __enter__
    assert self.layer.startEditing()
AssertionError
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Furthermore, probably `len(f['NEIGHBORS'].split(','))`, otherwise it will just return the length of the string

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is because you are creating and trying to edit an invalid layer. You do not need to create a new layer object at all. All you need is this:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fld_ix = lyr.fields().lookupField('NUMBER')
atts_map = {f.id(): {fld_ix: len(f['NEIGHBORS'].split(','))} for f in lyr.getFeatures() if f['NEIGHBORS'] != NULL}
#print(atts_map)
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(atts_map)
```

Select your layer in the TOC and Run.

Test result:

[image]

You can find more information in the [Pyqgis Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modify-features).

Comment: @fcka, if your field value is really a list then `len(f['NEIGHBORS'])` is what you want. I have edited my answer. Please try it again.

Comment: @ Ben W , as much for me, it's not a list,
I think it's a dictionary with keys corresponding to the id of the objects and with values corresponding to the number of the objects.
so how can we retrieve in a new attribute only the list of dict.values()?

Comment: @fcka You must do some debugging. Print `f['NEIGHBORS]` for a few of your features and see what is printed. Also do `print(type(f['NEIGHBORS']))` and see what is returned.

Comment: And what error did you get with the above code?? It's not making sense to me because when you tried mt original answer, the error was `'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. That means that `f['NEIGHBORS']` returns a list object, so `len(f['NEIGHBORS'])` should work.

Comment: @ Ben W with the following command:
'layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
     print(f['NEIGHBORS'])

returns:
51,262
NULL
311
NULL
215
234,371
234
45
100

with the command
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
     print(type(f['NEIGHBORS']))

returns:
<class 'str'>
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
...'

Comment: @fcka OK, then you need to skip features with NULL attribute. Answer edited again. BTW, how many features are there in your layer?

Comment: I removed the lines where neighbors is null and it works perfectly.

Comment: @fcka, so it's working? If so would you mind accepting the answer??

Comment: @ Ben W       Yes of course